# why do I get an error runtime '91' when using Find method vba

Tags: excel, vba, find, runtime-error

I get a run-time error '91' everytime I try to use the find method in a range. I have an array of dates("A1:A5") from which I get the highest one by using a max method, but then I want to get another value which is column B ("B1:B5") and in the same row of the highest date I have found before.

```
Dim wkbFrom As Workbook
Dim wsmb As Sheets
Dim MBSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim rowTMO as long
Dim carica_range As Range
Dim TMOcarica_range As Range

'Define The MB worksheet
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(MBPath)
Set wsmb = wkbFrom.Worksheets
Set MBSheet2 = wsmb(CStr("Foglio1"))

For m = 2 To row_counter
Set TMOcarica_range = DataSheet.Cells(m, DataSheet.Range("TMO_carica").Column)
Set carica_range = DataSheet.Cells(m, DataSheet.Range("data_carico_magazzino").Column)

'here I put some other code that fills the respective values in the MBSheet2.("A1:B5") arrange

'Find the max value in the ("A1:A5") array and give the values date format
carica_range.value = WorksheetFunction.Max(MBSheet2.Range("A1:A5"))
carica_range.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
MBSheet2.Range("A1:A5").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
rowTMO = MBSheet2.Columns(1).Find(carica_range, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
TMOcarica_range.Value = MBSheet2.Cells(rowTMO, "B").Value

Next m
```

Comment: `carica_range` is Nothing - you have not set it to anything.

Comment: Also do not. directly work with `.Find` like this. Check if `.Find` returns something or not. You may want to see [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Best to specify the `LookAt` parameter too.

Comment: You are right I didn't put the entire code so I forgot to put the part where I defined `carica_range`. (I have edited the question)  and given that I am obtaining the max value from the arrange I created, then the value that I want to find with `.Find` is for sure present, that is why I was not using the check for Nothing. Also what should I specify as `LookAt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range.Find returns a range object; if the search fails it returns nothing.
The use you make of it is not correct; you should assign the value returned by Find to a variable of type range, check that the variable does not contain Nothing and, only then, perform operations on it.

```
Dim wkbFrom As Workbook
Dim wsmb As Sheets
Dim MBSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim rowTMO As Long
Dim load_range As Range
Dim TMOload_range As Range
Dim Fnd As Range

    load_range.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max (MBSheet2.Range ("A1: A5"))
    load_range.NumberFormat = "dd / mm / yyyy"
    MBSheet2.Range ("A1: A5"). NumberFormat = "dd / mm / yyyy"
    Set Fnd = MBSheet2.Columns (1) .Find (load_range, LookIn: = xlValues)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        rowTMO = Fnd.Row
        TMOload_range.Value = MBSheet2.Cells (rowTMO, "B"). Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
```

PS: Range.Find doesn't work well with dates.

Comment: Thank you, I have not used exactly this code but as you told me that .find didn't work well with dates then I used vlookup, but the problem was that I was using directly the `carica_range` instead of a variant. Therefore, I declared a variant that would be the result of the `worksheetfunction.max("A1:A5")`, then I would use the vlookup with this variant `worksheetfunction.vlookup(maxVariant, MBSheet2.range("A1:B5"),2)` which would return the value on another variant. For both of the variants I performed the error check as you showed on your code. Thank you, I was desperate.